# How to redirect not working?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, redirect

redirect does not work while in the network has been redirected , tetepi in the browser does not work ?

this controler

```html
$this -> db -> trans_begin();
  $data['t_purchase_order_detail'] = $data_detail;
  $data['t_purchase_order_header'] = $data_header;
  
  if($this->input->post('save_confirm') == 'confirm'){
   $data['t_purchase_order_header']['doc_status']  = "AWAITING";
   $approval_status = request_approval($this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id, 'PUR_ORD', $document_number);
  }
  $this->purchase_order_model->edit($data,array('doc_id'=>$this->input->post('doc_id')));
  $this->inventory_model->recalculate();
  if($this->input->post('save_confirm') == 'save'){
   redirect('purchase/purchase_order');
   return true;
  }
  $this -> sky -> trans_end();
```

Comment: have you loaded the url helper ? `$this->load->helper('url')` || autoload ?

Comment: I 've put it on __construct

Comment: it is already included in the router ? $route['purchase/purchase_order'] = purchase_order_controller

Comment: comment out // return true; and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use redirect function, you need to load the Url helper like this :

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

In the codeigniter documentation we have this description:

```
redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL)
Parameters: 
$uri (string) – URI string
$method (string) – Redirect method (‘auto’, ‘location’ or ‘refresh’)
$code (string) – HTTP Response code (usually 302 or 303)
```

So try to use you redirect function like this:

```
redirect('purchase/purchase_order','auto');
```

You can try with refresh instead of auto.

You can do this with php function

```
header('Location: purchase/purchase_order');
```